# Grails IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: exception, grails, jetty, war

I deploy a war made with "grails war" to a jetty server.

As far as I can determine, Grails builds with Sun JDK 1.6.0_17-b04 and jetty runs on Sun JDK 1.6.0.16 (both on linux).

```
2010-08-18 07:33:47.018:WARN::Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException:     
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: the number of constructors during runtime and compile time for java.lang.ClassLoader do not match. Expected 3 but got 2:
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: the number of constructors during runtime and compile time for java.lang.ClassLoader do not match. Expected 3 but got 2
at grails.plugin.scopedproxy.AlwaysReloadableSmartClassLoader.<init>(AlwaysReloadableSmartClassLoader.groovy:28)
at grails.plugin.scopedproxy.ScopedProxyUtils.wrapInSmartClassLoader(ScopedProxyUtils.groovy:154)
```

How can this problem be solved or debugged further?

Answer (score 11):

Run `grails clean` before you run `grails war`.

Comment: clean helped me too. it was a version conflict in my case. happened only when debugging.

Comment: any time I've seen this, I've fixed it through grails clean as well

Answer (score 3):

According to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7827742/539048), Groovy code that uses exceptions that was compiled with a version of Java prior to 7 is not compatible with Java 7.

More information can be found [here](http://blog.proxerd.pl/article/how-to-fix-incompatibleclasschangeerror-for-your-groovy-projects-running-on-jdk7).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into a JAR conflict.   Namely your build environment is using one jar, and runtime (Jetty) is using a conflicting jar.   This used to often happen with various XML parsing stacks.

Try looking at the Jars used by jetty and compare them to the ones in your project.