# Geb - IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: java, groovy, geb

I'm just starting out with Geb and am encountering this error when inputting sample code from the Book of Geb:

```
import geb.Browser


Browser.drive {
    go "http://google.com/ncr"

    // make sure we actually got to the page
    assert title == "Google"

    // enter wikipedia into the search field
    $("input", name: "q").value("wikipedia")

    // wait for the change to results page to happen
    // (google updates the page dynamically without a new request)
    waitFor { title.endsWith("Google Search") }

    // is the first link to wikipedia?
    def firstLink = $("li.g", 0).find("a.l")
    assert firstLink.text() == "Wikipedia"

    // click the link
    firstLink.click()

    // wait for Google's javascript to redirect to Wikipedia
    waitFor { title == "Wikipedia" }
}
```

I am encountering this exception:

```
Caught: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: the number of constructors during runtime and compile time for java.lang.Exception do not match. Expected 4 but got 5
    at geb.error.GebException.<init>(GebException.groovy:20)
    at geb.waiting.WaitTimeoutException.<init>(WaitTimeoutException.groovy:30)
    at geb.waiting.Wait.waitFor(Wait.groovy:108)
        .......
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you using Java 7 by any chance? Groovy code that uses exceptions that was compiled with < Java 7 is not compatible with Java 7.

Comment: Yes I believe I am using RE7 - thank you so much, will try and update

Comment: not getting that error anymore - thanks for the info! is that documented anywhere by any chance?

Comment: See [this blog post](http://blog.proxerd.pl/article/how-to-fix-incompatibleclasschangeerror-for-your-groovy-projects-running-on-jdk7) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Geb is compatible with Java7 as of 0.7.1. If you are below that you should upgrade. SEe: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEB-194